# Is there a way to code format info.plist file like prettier?

Tags: ios, react-native, prettier, code-formatting, info.plist

If the info.plist file changes, the PR changes and it's very cumbersome to modify. Is there a way to modify it through github action or CI build? Or I'm looking for a way to keep it consistent through script. If anyone knows, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [XML Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DotJoshJohnson.xml) on VSCode. That might be what you're looking for.